# How to find all vertices having multi properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython

Let's imagine I have the following two verices:

```
g.addV('set-test').\
    property('mySet','one').\
    property(set_, 'mySet','two').\
    property(id_,'set-test1').next()

g.addV('set-test2').\
        property('mySet','three').next()
```

I could query them and get the results:

```
g.V().hasLabel("set-test").valueMap().toList()
[{'mySet': ['one', 'two']}]
```

and

```
g.V().hasLabel("set-test2").valueMap().toList()
[{'mySet': ['three']}]
```

Question:
How could I find all vertices which have a multi property?
e.g.
in this case I would like to get "set-test" back.

Comment: I see at least one vote to close. Please be aware that to those familiar with Gremlin, this question makes perfect sense and the sample data provided allows for easy reproduction of the issue and made crafting an answer (see below) very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for including a sample graph as part of the question. That makes writing a tested answer much easier.

Here is a simple solution (below). This may be expensive on a large graph, but you can just filter by counting them.

```java
gremlin> g.V().where(values('mySet').count().is(gt(1)))

==>v[set-test1]
```